# how parallelize this function

Tags: openmp

I have a function which is quite time consuming and it goes like this since the value of n is very large

```
sum=0; for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     a=func(i,b);
     c=func(i,a);
     sum+=c;  
}
```

Is it possible to parallelize this loop using openMp?

Comment: We're gonna need to see more of the code. Right now, the code doesn't do anything since you overwrite `c` at each iteration.

Comment: When implementing this, make sure that `func` is reentrant when it is called by multiple threads.

Comment: You have completely changed your question. I suggest you make a new question instead and revert this one back to the original. So I'll answer it separately.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the short way:

```
int sum = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int a = func(i,b);
        int c = func(i,a);
        sum += c;
    }
```

Here's a longer (but more flexible) way:

```
int sum = 0;

#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int local_sum = 0;

#pragma omp for
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            a = func(i,b);
            c = func(i,a);
            local_sum += c;
        }

#pragma omp critical
        {
            sum += local_sum;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank u mystical :) is it possible to use it for arrays too? say i wanted it to be sum[i]=c??

Comment: Yes. And if each iteration is writing to a different element of the destination array, you don't need `reduction` or synchronization at all. (If this answers your question, you can accept my answer by clicking on the green check-mark. Same for your previous question.)

Comment: Mystical, i modified the question a bit, i tried working on it but wasnt able to..could you please help me out here